# How can I solve $\begin{equation}\ \begin{cases}xu_x-yu_y=u\\^u|_{\Gamma }\:=\:g\end{cases}\end{equation}$ (Method of Characteristics along curve Γ)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

$$
  \begin{equation}
    \
    \begin{cases}
      xu_x-yu_y=u, &  U=\left\{\left(x,y\right):\:x>0,\:y>1\right\} \\
      ^u|_{\Gamma }\:=\:g, & \Gamma =\left\{\left(x,y\right):\:x>0,\:y=1\right\}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
$$

This is the full PDE with all conditions

We just went through the theory of the Method of Characteristics (we basically did chapter 3.2 in Evan's book), but right now, I don't see a way how to start calculating this as we don't have a parametrization for our curve $\Gamma$ given (or do we?).

And because of that, I don't see a way to apply our "new knowledge" to that problem

Comment: And how can I find this suitable parametrization? How do I know that it is suitable?

Comment: The curve $\Gamma$ is obviously parametrized by $x$.

Comment: @HansLundmark:  Yes, $\Gamma$ where the boundary values are given is parameterized by $x$, but the method of characteristics needs some family of curves that intersect $\Gamma$ and along which the PDE will reduce to an ODE that we can more easily solve, thus "transporting" values of $u(x,y)$ into the interior region.

Comment: @hardmath: Yes, I know how the method of characteristics works, but in the question it says “as we don't have a parametrization for our curve $\Gamma$ given (or do we?)”. All I'm saying is that obviously we *do* have a parametrization for $\Gamma$. Of course, that's a rather trivial part of the problem, and the fun begins when we want to determine the characteristics. But it seems to me that that was actually what was asked (although it's not 100% clear, to be honest).

Comment: The general solution of the PDE is $$u(x,y)=xF(xy)$$ $F$ is an arbitrary function. According to the specified condition the function $F$ can be determined. This leads to the solution $$u(x,y)=\frac{g}{y}$$ Put it into the PDE and check that it agrees with the PDE and with the condition.

Comment: "But it seems to me that that was actually what was asked (although it's not 100% clear, to be honest)" yes that's what I was asking about